# 5e Oath Selection

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

I am trying to find a Oath for a Paladin (5th Edition). My DM has explained that I can choose from the oaths in PHB, Sword Coast, Morda, and Xanithar's. I can't seem to settle on one oath, because none of them seem to fit.

The paladin's story:

Exiled noble that fled execution because they helped a commoner.

Came to the new world after swimming a long time, saved by what seemed like divine intervention.

The paladin has taken protection as the fighting style, and uses it quite a bit. The paladin is very violent towards evil doers, but tries to be helpful to commoners wherever possible.

Dislikes nobles a lot, but is much too trusting of commoners.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Have you taken the [tour]? It's a great place to start to learn how things work here. Unfortunately this kind of question isn't a great fit for this site. We prefer question that have non-subjective answers. See the [help-center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for advice on asking questions. If there is a problem you are trying to solve with this choice that better suits the site [edit] your post so we can help you out. Don't be discouraged and happy gaming!

Comment: @John See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: Your question may be better suited for a discussion forum; [we have a curated list here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)